# tsc.js Microsoft JScript runtime error after installing 0.9 version

Tags: typescript, runtime-error, jscript, tsc

I keep getting a compile error after installing version 0.9 of TypeScript. Here's the error:

> tsc.js(21630, 17) Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value
>   of the property 'trailingTrivia': object is null or undefined

And this is a snippet of the code I'm getting the error on:

```
    /// <reference path="..\..\Scripts\Typescript\jquery.d.ts" />
    /// <reference path="..\Typescript\kendo\2013.1.703\kendo.web.d.ts" />
    /// <reference path="..\..\Metadata\newMetadata.ts" />
    /// <reference path="metadataFunctions.ts" />
    /// <reference path="contractors.ts" />
    /// <reference path="kendoWrappers\KendoWrappers.ts" />
```

I've found the tsc.js in the following directory:

> c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript

In the file there is a property used called 'trailingTrivia' but it seems to me this should not be my concern at all.

I can't find anything of the sort on the internet anywhere so I'm a bit lost here. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Try removing references one by one

Comment: I removed all off them and still get the error. Something in the install is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

This is a weird one. In one of our scripts the following was formely excepted by TypeScript but in v0.9 this causes the error above.

export function pathName => pathname;